# Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding, removing `\H'

Tags: hyperref, input-encodings

I've got the message when I try to convert my project into pdf:

> Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding, removing `\H' on input line 73.

I use MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter 1.0.

What does input mean? My main tex file? If so:

```
\hypersetup{
%bookmarks=true,            % show bookmarks bar?
unicode=false,             % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
pdftitle={\vikcim},        % title
pdfauthor={\vikszerzo},    % author
pdfsubject={\vikdoktipus}, % subject of the document
pdfcreator={\vikszerzo},   % creator of the document
pdfproducer={Producer},    % producer of the document
pdfkeywords={keywords},    % list of keywords
pdfnewwindow=true,         % links in new window
colorlinks=true,           % false: boxed links; true: colored links
linkcolor=black,           % color of internal links
citecolor=black,           % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=black,           % color of file links
    urlcolor=black             % color of external links
}% this is line 73
```

Earlier:

```
\newcommand{\vikszerzo}{string1}
\newcommand{\vikkonzulens}{string2}
\newcommand{\vikcim}{string3}
\newcommand{\viktanszek}{string4}
\newcommand{\vikdoktipus}{string5}
\newcommand{\vikdepartmentr}{string6}
```

My usepackages:

```
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please, make a minimal example that produces the problem (and remove all packages that are not essential for it).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`PD1` encoding is used by `hyperref` for bookmark text. So it seems hungarian accents will not appear in you bookmarks.

What I don't understand is that you are using `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` which should get things right by using `PU` encoding for bookmarks, but later you turn unicode bookmarks off again with

```
\hypersetup{
  unicode=false,             % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: I use a sample project where there was unicode=false and I got that message. I added [unicode] because I read that it will help on my message and I did not realize that I also did the contrary. Well obviously it didn't help. But the error message disappeared now that I deleted unicode=false. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I tried, but It tells: Please login or register to vote for this post.
(click on this box to dismiss) Oh yeah, and I AM logged in. When I first used stackexchange there wasn even a need for registrarion....

Comment: @imzs No offence meant. It seems there are sometimes problems with logins...